# Matrix represents same rotation with different euler angles

Tags: 3d, rotation, mathematics

I have Transform component storing it's rotation as Quaternion.
Transform has set/getEulerAngles (rotation order oy, ox, oz).
I want to rotate object in any direction but while testing I get jumping(glitch) objects stop rotating at specific angles.

Euler angles in problem frames:

**1)** *oy*  0  *ox*  -90 *oz*  0  - previous frame.

**2)** *oy* 180 *ox*  -90 *oz* 180 - next frame after incrementing angle of the object.

my increment looks like:

```
tr->setEulerAngles(tr->eulerAngles()+Vector3(5,0,0));//rotate around ox by 5 degrees
```

visually this rotations are **equal**, but when I get angles **2)** from quaternion and increment them it starts rotating in oposite direction, next frame rotation is again as **1)**, so there is infinite loop at this rotation (some kind of black hole;-)).
What can it be? Something wrong with math?

Comment: Your problem is more or less the definition of [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

Comment: From a practical perspective, the best way to fix this is to avoid Euler angles altogether; precompute a quaternion that corresponds to a 5-degree rotation about ox and just multiply your current orientation by that 5-degree rotation each frame.

Comment: As intuitive as Euler angles seem at first, they are equally that evil when you go beyond 2d. In 3d, avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Unity3d has same problem when rotation around ox axis. Thanks for help, I solved problem multiplying current rotation by quaternion created from axis angle. Comment about gimbal lock and euler angles equally evil)) I'll mark as an answer if you write it there. I thought that using quaternion do not make gimbal lock at all, but conversion to from euler angles does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) is the answer, avoid using euler angles even converting to and from quaternion, use multiplication by quaternion created from angle axis.

Unity3d has same problem when rotating around ox axis:

```
transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(5,0,0); //problem
```